# Optimize the query PostgreSql-8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have rails controller coding as below:

```
@checked_contact_ids = @list.contacts.all(
  :conditions => {
    "contacts_lists.contact_id" => @list.contacts.map(&:id),
    "contacts_lists.is_checked" => true
  }
).map(&:id)
```

its equivalent to sql

```
SELECT *
FROM "contacts"
INNER JOIN "contacts_lists" ON "contacts".id = "contacts_lists".contact_id
WHERE ("contacts_lists".list_id = 67494 )
```

This above query takes more time to run, I want another way to run the same query with minimum time.

Is anyone knows please notice me  Or is it possible? or is the above query enough for give output?

I am waiting information...................

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem with your original AR query is that it isn't doing any joins at all; you pull a bunch of objects out of the database via `@list.contacts` and then throw most of that work away to get just the IDs.

A first step would be to replace the `"contacts_lists.contact_id" => @list.contacts.map(&:id)` with a `:joins => 'contact_lists'` but you'd still be pulling a bunch of stuff out of the database, instantiating a bunch of objects, and then throwing it all away with the `.map(&:id)` to get just ID numbers.

You know SQL already so I'd probably go straight to SQL via a convenience method on your List model (or whatever `@list` is), something like this:

```
def checked_contact_ids
    connection.execute(%Q{
        SELECT contacts.id
        FROM contacts
        INNER JOIN contacts_lists ON contacts.id = contacts_lists.contact_id
        WHERE contacts_lists.list_id    = #{self.id}
          AND contacts_lists.is_checked = 't'
    }).map { |r| r['id'] }
end
```

And then, in your controller:

```
@checked_contact_ids = @list.checked_contact_ids
```

If that isn't fast enough then review your indexes on the `contacts_lists` table.

There's no good reason not go straight to SQL when you know exactly what data you need and you need it fast; just keep the SQL isolated inside your models and you shouldn't have any problems.